# round value to 2 decimals javascript

Tags: jquery, rounding

I have a small issue with the final value, i need to round to 2 decimals.

```
var pri='#price'+$(this).attr('id').substr(len-2);
            $.get("sale/price?output=json", { code: v },
               function(data){
                 $(pri).val(Math.round((data / 1.19),2));
            });
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Solution: `$(pri).val(Math.round((data / 1.19 * 100 )) / 100);`

Comment: Better solution: `$(pri).val(data.toFixed(2))`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just multiply the number by 100, round, and divide the resulting number by 100.

Comment: Do you mean $(pri).val(Math.round((data * 19 / 100),2)); ?

Comment: unless of course the number could overflow by increasing it's size.

Comment: @Dario Not exactly sure where you're getting `,2` from.

Comment: @TopGunCoder But we're dealing with prices here ;)

Comment: in php the round is round(value,2) and you get the last 2 decimals.

Comment: not sure for javascript if is the same... is because im asking for a push of help.

Comment: @Dario Oh, well then I don't see what the issue is here other than the fact that `2.2` should be `2`. As for Javascript, you have the use the method I described in my answer.

Comment: Resolved, $(pri).val(Math.round((data / 1.19 * 100 )) / 100);

Comment: by far the easiest solution!

Answer (score 77):

If you want it visually formatted to two decimals as a string (for output) use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var priceString = someValue.toFixed(2);
```

The answer by @David has two problems:

1. It leaves the result as a floating point number, and consequently holds the possibility of displaying a particular result with many decimal places, e.g. `134.1999999999` instead of `"134.20"`.
2. If your value is an integer or rounds to one tenth, you will not see the additional decimal value:

   ```
   var n = 1.099;
   (Math.round( n * 100 )/100 ).toString() //-> "1.1"
   n.toFixed(2)                            //-> "1.10"

   var n = 3;
   (Math.round( n * 100 )/100 ).toString() //-> "3"
   n.toFixed(2)                            //-> "3.00"
   ```

And, as you can see above, using `toFixed()` is also far easier to type. ;)

Comment: `toFixed(2)` rounds 1.025 to 1.02. That is not correct. If you use 1.026 it rounds correctly but not with 5 thus this rounding is wrong.

Comment: @MrSmith That's because it is not actually, exactly `1.025`. `(1.025).toFixed(20)` gives `"1.02499999999999991118"`, which is the closest JavaScript (and any language using [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) 64-bit floating point numbers) can come to representing your desired `1.025`. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/) and ...