# Addition of two forms in the third form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addition

Working on javascript to (+) from two forms and show it on the third one, but having a issue with that I want it to round the decimal to 2 as ,XX. And result is now showing in dot (.), how can I change it to show in comma ? It only let user write decimal values in dot, how can I change it to comma?

`Jsfiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/eYj8B/4/

Comment: good question thumbs up

Answer (score 2):

You are missing ***semi colon (;)*** end of *var inputs*. and `value.toString().replace('.', ',')` to output value replace `dot (.)` to `comma (,)`.

**Check this** <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eYj8B/9/)</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var inputs = $('input[name="M_Fritt_Klor"],input[name="M_Total_Klor"]');
      output = $('input[name="M_Bundet_Klor"]');
    function parse(value) {
        return parseFloat(value.replace(',','.'));
    }
  inputs.keyup(function() {
      var value = parse(inputs[0].value)+parse(inputs[1].value);
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
          output.val(value.toString().replace('.', ','));
      }
  });
});
```

Yes, its work comma instead of dot.

#### Result

[image]

Hope this help you

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to change it to only use comma in decimal values and show the result in comma ? Now it only supports dot (.): https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fc5c9wknbgtjtx/teste.png

Comment: Update answer check it

Comment: I want the result as it showing to be 23,6 not 23.6.

Comment: OP has a correct `var` statement in the linked fiddle code. Your code creates a global `output` variable...

Comment: i try but unable to success @user3185936

Comment: Thanks for giving a shot user1153551. I am also very unsure how to it.

Comment: hey i got idea why u can not use regexp. please try to set value.replace(/./g, ',')

Comment: Nice, jsfiddle is down i think: 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Thanks! I have a small question, If I try to not addition but minus how can I round after the decimal to ,XX ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk30qr70z9hcqsk/30-03-2014%2017-10-41.png

Comment: how many round u want ? you can join using jquery join function

Comment: Sorry, I am new to join function. I want to round it to two decimals. Like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666752/round-value-to-2-decimals-javascript